# URL not found error in laravel4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I added this to my routes

```
Route::get('account/create',array(

     'as' => 'account-create',
     'uses' => 'AccountController@createGet'


    ));
```

then when i go to public/account/create , i got a 
The requested URL /webproj/public/account/create was not found on this server error.
Then when I tried it to my /webproj/server.php it works.

Comment: can you remove the public from your url and check.. Also check controller, method name and spelling

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems:

1) If you still need to use `/public` in your URL, the correct form would is:

```
http://server/project/public/index.php/account/create
```

2) You should not be using `/public`, so you need correctly configure your webserver virtual hosts, to point directly to `/public` so you can just access your urls as

```
http://server/project/account/create
```

3) `/webproj/server.php` should not be accessible and should not be used, Laravel needs it only for running

```
php artisan serve
```